# Problem with bootstrap card-columns - showing mess

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a masonry cards and I'm using bootstrap 4 for this, everything is okay until I add the card-columns class.[image: mess]

My html is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
               <div class="col-12">
                      <div class="row">

                        <?php   echo 
    '<div class="col-md-2">
                     <div class="card-columns">
                    <div class="card">
                         <a href="'.$global_url.'post/'.$row['post_seo_url'].'"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="'.$global_url.'uploads/post_thumbnails/'.$row['post_thumbnail'].'" alt="Thumbnail"></a>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">'.$row['post_name'].'</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">'.short_post($row['post_text'],$rand).' <a href="'.$global_url.'post/'.$row['post_seo_url'].'">read more..</a></p>
                            <p class="card-text">
                                <small class="text-muted">Author: '.GetProfileNickName($row['post_author']).'</small>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     </div>
                </div>'; ?>
                      </div>
               </div>
           </div>
</div>
```

I'm using PHP get the information and print it as a card.

Reference for `card-columns` in [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns).

Comment: Could you add the CSS involved?

Comment: Well I cannot add the whole css, I'm using Bootstrap v4.3.1

Comment: What's the behavior / display if you remove the following line `<div class="col-md-2">` and its corresponding closing `</div>` tag?

Comment: the card are becoming bigger and each card on new line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict cards per column just use a structure as:

> .container > .row > .col-xx

Ref:
https://www.codeply.com/go/AP1MpYKY2H/bootstrap-4-card-deck-columns-per-row

If you don't have a problem with restricting per row

> .container-fluid > .card-columns > .cards (looped) should be enough.

Thank you

Comment: The problem now its that the whole section becomes smaller (small cards and big cards)

Comment: It's because the container, use container fluid or adjust the padding

Answer (score 0):

Its because the php function which is printing out the cards have `<div class="col-md-2">`, and with `card-columns` its not possible because bootstrap is setting them to responsive eg: 3 columns or 4, I removed the `col-md` and now everything is okay.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">

                      <div class="row">
<div class="col-12">

                        <?php   echo 
    '<div class="col-md-2">
                     <div class="card-columns">
                    <div class="card">
                         <a href="'.$global_url.'post/'.$row['post_seo_url'].'"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="'.$global_url.'uploads/post_thumbnails/'.$row['post_thumbnail'].'" alt="Thumbnail"></a>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">'.$row['post_name'].'</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">'.short_post($row['post_text'],$rand).' <a href="'.$global_url.'post/'.$row['post_seo_url'].'">read more..</a></p>
                            <p class="card-text">
                                <small class="text-muted">Author: '.GetProfileNickName($row['post_author']).'</small>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     </div>
                </div>'; ?>
                      </div>
               </div>
           </div>
</div>
```

you have declared the col-12 div before declaring the row

Answer (score 0):

This is your code what you want, You just repeat the `"card"` class block, if you want to declare different columns  style just create a baby change in css, don't need to declare `col` class in inside of `card-columns`

```
column-count: 3; // the count number is your choose, depend what column you want
```

```
               <div class="card-columns">
                    <div class="card">
                         <a href="#" alt="Thumbnail"></a>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">Card text here <a href="#">read more..</a>
                            </p>
                            <p class="card-text">
                                <small class="text-muted">Author: </small>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```